# How to read text in edittext in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I  am getting text in **edit text** as string,but I want to get as integer. I used.

```
Edittext.text.toString().toInt()
```

Then app is not working.tell me how to convert input text from string to int and i want to store this value in a variable . Help me.correct answers will be appreciated.

Comment: No problem! Just make sure to click the 'check mark' if someone answers your question, people get pretty crazy on here about it. The 'up arrow' is more like a vote for being helpful, even if it isn't the actual answer.

Comment: @rohithsai what is the exception you are getting?

Comment: App is crashing

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
int test = Integer.valueof(Edittext.text.toString());
```

UPDATE:
Per Mohammed Atif, this solution may not work in Kotlin... but I will leave it in case it helps elsewhere.

Comment: Unfortunately this works for Java but not Kotlin. What he wrote in question should be working unless he is getting number format exception.

Comment: Thats funny, I have seen a few things about Kotlin but never realized it was completely separate... my bad!